# Execute some code when a celery chain has completed

Tags: python, django, celery

I have the following code that starts a celery chain by visiting a url. The chain arguments are passed through a query parameter like: `/process_pipeline/?pipeline=task_a|task_c|task_b`. In order to avoid launching several similar chained tasks (if for instance someone refresh the page) I use a simple cache locking system.

I have a timeout on the cache, but what I'm missing here is a way to release the cache when the chain has commpleted.

Any idea?

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task


registry = {}

def register(fn):
    registry[fn.__name__] = fn

@shared_task
def task_a(*args, **kwargs):
    print('task a')

@shared_task
def task_b(*args, **kwargs):
    print('task b')

@shared_task
def task_c(*args, **kwargs):
    print('task c')

register(task_a)
register(task_b)
register(task_c)
```

views.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from django.core.cache import cache as memcache
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.utils.hashcompat import md5_constructor as md5
from celery import chain
from .tasks import registry


LOCK_EXPIRE = 60 * 5  # Lock expires in 5 minutes


def process_pipeline(request):
    pipeline = request.GET.get('pipeline')
    hexdigest = md5(pipeline).hexdigest()
    lock_id = 'lock-{0}'.format(hexdigest)

    # cache.add fails if if the key already exists
    acquire_lock = lambda: memcache.add(lock_id, None, LOCK_EXPIRE)
    # memcache delete is very slow, but we have to use it to take
    # advantage of using add() for atomic locking
    release_lock = lambda: memcache.delete(lock_id)

    if acquire_lock():
        args = [registry[p].s() for p in pipeline.split('|')]
        task = chain(*args).apply_async()
        memcache.set(lock_id, task.id)

        return redirect('celery-task_status', task_id=task.id)
    else:
        task_id = memcache.get(lock_id)
        return redirect('celery-task_status', task_id=task_id)



from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('aafilters.views',
    url(r'^process_pipeline/$', 'process_pipeline', name="process_pipeline"),
)
```

Comment: On tasks, there is a method called `after_return`, but no similar thing on chains it seems like. See <http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes>

Answer (score 0):

I have never used it, but I think you should take a look at [Celery Canvas](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html). It seems to be what you want.